# SASS: transparize to HEX and not RGBA (with white background)

Tags: css, sass

I want to calculate color values in a variables file from one HEX primary color but if I use `rgba` or `opacify` SASS always transforms the color to RGBA (like `rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.5)`).

What I really want is the primary color with the specific opacity, if the background color would be white in HEX!

That is because it don't want the background of my website to shine through!

Is that possible? I couldn't find something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Oh sorry, after formulating the question I noticed it may not be exactly an opacity problem and than I was able to find:

`mix($my-color, #fff, 25%)`

(https://makandracards.com/makandra/42500-sass-how-to-convert-an-rgba-color-to-its-rgb-look-alike)